# Paginador AJAX. ¿Cómo obtener la URL del GET o el POST en AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

En una página web como [esta](https://tienda.consum.es/consum/Consum.html) donde se tiene una paginación de productos mediante AJAX, ¿cómo puedo obtener la URL a la que se hace GET o POST para obtener los productos? ¿Existe alguna manera de conseguirla?

Llevo un par de días intentándolo mediante firebug e **imagino que habrá alguna manera de "interceptar" ese GET o POST**.

Otra opción que he probado es la de leer el código fuente, buscando el JavaScript en al que se hace la llamada AJAX pero me parece demasiado complejo.

Un saludo.

Edito:
Para que quede más claro. Imagina que en una página web está el siguiente código ajax:

```
$.ajax(
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://loquesea.com/carpeta/pagina/lo/que/sea.php",
    ...);
```

Cuando se hace scroll al final se llama a este código para traerse los productos y mostrarlos. Pues bien, necesito conocer esa url.

Comment: por que quieres obtener la url?

Comment: Para obtener los productos mediante un crawler.

Comment: cual es el ajax que no entiendes?

Comment: No es que no entienda el ajax, es que no encuentro el ajax que hace el get o el post para traerse los productos y necesitaría la url.

Comment: Probablemente porque el que diseño la web no queria que lo encontraras :3

Answer (score 4):

Una opción es sobrescribir el constructor nativo [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Así por ejemplo:

```js
// Guardamos el constructor nativo
var orgXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;
function newXHR() {
  // Usamos el constructor original para crear el ajax
  var xhr = new orgXHR();
  // Guardamos la funcion original open
  var orgOpen = xhr.open;
  // Reemplazamos la funcion con una custom
  xhr.open = function() {
    console.log(arguments[1]);
    // Aplicamos la llamada original
    return orgOpen.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Reemplazamos el constructor nativo
window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;

// Helper
function ajax(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}

// Ajax 1
ajax('http://google.com');
// Ajax 2
ajax('http://es.stackoverflow.com');
// Ajax 3 usando JQuery
$.get('http://developer.mozilla.com');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Y si no usa jQuery? Su ejemplo usa jQuery pero no me queda claro que sea un requisito de la pregunta. Aún así marco como positiva porque da una solución parcial útil.

Comment: @lilezek, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: ¿Pero a eso todavía se le puede hacer bypass no? Usando elementos DOM de tipo script src="url a la que hacer get"... El debugger del explorador web sin embargo captura todas las conexiones de todas las formas posibles.

Comment: @lilezek, usar un tag `script` no es hacer ajax.  La pregunta apunta puntualmente a llamadas `ajax` usando `javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Usando el debugger de Google Chrome puedes capturar todas las peticiones que viajan por la red en un apartado llamado *Network*. Seguramente con Mozilla Firefox puedas hacerlo también. Cada vez que se hace una petición AJAX a otro sitio o para otro documento del mismo sitio debería reflejarse en la lista de conexiones.